# Compiler divergence in delayed template instantiation

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

I want to trigger a `static_assert`, when my base class does not implement a member function.

```cpp
#include<type_traits>
  
template<typename T>
struct AlwaysFalse : public std::false_type {};

struct B
{
  template<typename S>
  void foo(){}
};

template <typename T,typename S>
struct A:T
{
  auto foo(){
    if constexpr (requires{T::template foo<S>();})
    return 1;
    else
       static_assert(AlwaysFalse<A>::value,
                    "foo is not implemented.");
  }
};

int main()
{
A<B,double> a;
a.foo();
}
```

This compiles in gcc 12.2 but fails to compile with clang 16 and also clang trunk.
If the member function `foo` is not a template also clang compiles it.

**Which compiler is correct here?** I suppose GCC, since the base class member function is there and it should not read the `AlwaysFalse`. **Is my code even standard compliant c++?**

I also have a workaround, by creating an object in the requires expression

```cpp
if constexpr (requires(T t){t. template foo<S>();})
```

which compiles again for both compilers.

[Templated version](https://godbolt.org/z/oTWPhWE99)

[Non-templated version](https://godbolt.org/z/7b5xcvYYv)

[Workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/6Taj7c515)

Comment: `if constexpr (requires{T::template foo<S>();})` looks odd.

Comment: `foo` is not a static function, so it should be `if constexpr (requires{T{}.template foo<S>();})` (which is what you call the "workaround"). So I'm guessing it's a GCC bug. Also, your godbolt link has `foo` taking an `S` argument, but the code in the question doesn't. Please make it consistent.

Comment: I fixed the wrong link thanks. I wonder if it is really a question, if foo is `static` or not since `T::template foo<S>()` is the normal syntax of calling a base class member function, independent of the fact, that it is static or not, doesn't it? Maybe this can be overlooked, since I inherit from T `struct A : T`.

Comment: Oh, good point, for calling a base-class member that syntax should work. Maybe a clang bug then.

Comment: Yes I also feel it's a clang bug. Works fine with GCC, with clang needs your workaround to make it compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the correct capitalization is "Godbolt". The website is named after its creator, Matt Godbolt.

We can verify that the implementation divergence really has nothing to do with when compilers believe the substatements of `if constexpr` should be instantiated, by reducing the code to:

```
struct B
{
  template<typename S>
  void foo(){}
};

template <typename T,typename S>
struct A : T
{
  auto foo(){
    static_assert(requires{T::template foo<S>();});
  }
};

int main()
{
    A<B,double> a;
    a.foo();
}
```

Here again we see that only Clang has a problem with it. However, Clang has no problem if you actually have the statement `T::template foo<S>();` in the body of `A::foo`, so obviously Clang doesn't think it's actually ill-formed. Which means the `requires` expression should be true. Verdict: Clang bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I also refactored the code and created an issue at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/84020, which is exactly the same as you suggested. I'm sorry for writing the wrong name. I know it is named after Matt Godbolt but I thought it looks nicer with a big B. Maybe due to my non-stop CamelCase writing.